# Why the docker keeps both image and image container on VM?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, containers

The problem I encounter when working with large images is that Docker copies all the data when you create a container from it: so having 25gb image and a container for it totally takes about 50gb on Docker VM. **Am I doing something wrong or does Docker always function like that?** If so, why? E. g. in Git you may use the code directly after you clone the repo, most of the time you don't need to make one more additional copy of branch or whatever.

P. S. My use case is the following: I want to keep different versions of my MySQL database (because currently it is changed exclusively by developers and it happens not so often) and because I want to enable fast restoration (the only way MySQL allows restoration is from *.sql file and it takes 7 hours - too long to be able to play with db freely)

Comment: if you have a lot of data, you should use volumes. The image should be small, read https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/ and use Alpine or bitnami (the Debian light)  as base image, and your images will be smaller

Comment: @user2915097 added my use case to the question

Answer (score 0):

MySql databases use volumes at least the official image. You only need two containers withe same image using different named volumes:

```
docker create volume devdb
docker run --name devdb -v devdb:/var/lib/mysql -p 3306:3306-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

Then another for you:

```
docker create volume mydb
docker run --name mydb -v mydb:/var/lib/mysql -p 3307:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql
```

And I am afraid that docker copies all the image content into the new container. But I am not sure about that.

Regards